# find out if the android browser runs in an app or for itself

Tags: javascript, android, browser-detection

I am using an hybrid android app from [geyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/login?returl=http://www.appsgeyser.com/dashboard/widget/edit/).
I want to inform the user about the possibility to download this app, if he enters the mobile version of my website. the thing is, in the app runs a browser which views almost the same content as the mobile website.

how can I detect with JS if I am running in the App-Browser and not on the normal Browser?
I don't want to show the download Link of the App in the App.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested to see if there is anything in the GET header that will tell you?  Otherwise, it looks like you may be out of luck.

Comment: No I haven't. But greatly you can change the User-Agent string in the geyser's advanced settings. Hell yeah!

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is have a javascript function on your page like

```
setAndroidApp=function(){
    isAndroidApp=true;
}
```

and then, when you load your site through the android version (assuming you're using the Android [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) class ), you could make the function run when loading the page in the following manner

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:setAndroidApp()");
```

in which case, you'd have `isAndroidApp` set to `true` for the rest of your code if it's seen from the android app.

Comment: I am using an app from geyser ^^